# Argument used as a part of variable name inside a function in Python

Tags: python

I have following function:

```
def button_enter(self, event, type):
    if self.green_button_anim_on:
        return
    self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.green_button, image=self.green_button_image_hover)
```

This functions serves for the change of image of **green button** to "hover state" image when user hovers mouse over it.
What I am trying to do - I want to use this function universally, not just for the **green** button, but also for the **red** button, **quit** button etc. So I decided to pass the argument `type` to the function that will have values like `red`, `green`, `quit` etc.

Now I need to change the word **green** everywhere inside this function according to the value of argument `type`. What is the easiest way to do it please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the buttons and images in a `dict`:

```
self.buttons = { "green": self.green_button, ... }
self.images = {...}
...
```

Then, to retrieve the right objects:

```
self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.buttons[type], image=self.images[type])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have use [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) in python this way you can use meaningful names and map it to constant values.

Comment: add an example how enum helps the OP

Comment: yes, please, can you add some example? I am reading the description and usage of **enum**, but I am still not sure how exactly can I use it in my case... thanks!

Comment: Sure, I am just constructing a simple example. I will post it shortly
Can you maybe post your class structures and relevant code so that I can give an example relevant exactly to your case?